# PHP setlocale not working even with locales existing

Tags: php, setlocale

**ISSUE RESOLVED (see below)**

I have generated the locales on my server, I have confirmed that they exist (my locale -a provided below), but when I use:

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr_FR');
    or setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr_FR.utf8');
```

it doesn't work at all.

**Sample:**

```
    <?php
    setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr_FR.utf8');
    echo 'locale - '.setlocale(LC_TIME,'0');
    echo ' : month - '.strftime('%B');
    echo '<br />';

    setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr_FR');
    echo 'locale - '.setlocale(LC_TIME,'0');
    echo ' : month - '.strftime('%B');
    echo '<br />';

    setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr-FR');
    echo 'locale - '.setlocale(LC_TIME,'0');
    echo ' : month - '.strftime('%B');
    echo '<br />';

    setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr');
    echo 'locale - '.setlocale(LC_TIME,'0');
    echo ' : month - '.strftime('%B');
    echo '<br />';

    setlocale(LC_TIME,'french');
    echo 'locale - '.setlocale(LC_TIME,'0');
    echo ' : month - '.strftime('%B');
    echo '<br />';
    ?>
```

**Results:**

```
    locale - C : month - October
    locale - C : month - October
    locale - C : month - October
    locale - C : month - October
    locale - C : month - October
```

**locale -a (showing the fr locales):**

```
    fr_BE.utf8
    fr_CA.utf8
    fr_CH.utf8
    fr_FR.utf8
    fr_LU.utf8
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

okay, after posting this, I tried one more thing.  So for those experiencing the same issue, you need to set this first before setting the new locale:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "");
```

Comment: Check to make sure you have the locales installed and available on your server.  They have to exist in order to use them.  `locale -a`

Comment: That somehow worked for me, but I'd like to know why? (PS: Accept your own anser `:)`)

Comment: If locale is NULL or the empty string "", the locale names will be set from the values of environment variables with the same names as the above categories, or from "LANG". http://php.net/setlocale

Answer (score 4):

You have to restart php before use new installed locales.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the system default locale in Apache2, you just need to add (or uncomment) the following line in the /etc/apache2/envvars file :

```
. /etc/default/locale
```

Think to restart apache2 after this operation and clear your potential cache to check locale is well given to PHP.